# C# .NET WinForms Caret in TextBox won't follow mouse cursor on TextBox.DragDrop();

Tags: c#, .net, textbox, caret

I'm working on a C# WinForms .NET app in VS 2017 and I'm designing a feature in which text is dragged from a form to a textbox on another form. Ideally, the text should drop into the textbox at the textbox's caret, which follows the mouse's drag cursor wherever it goes. The problem is that the caret won't go any further than the spot just before the last character in the textbox.

Example:
The textbox contains the text "This is a test." I'll drag a label containing a single letter "A" from the other form to the textbox containing the aforementioned text. If I drag the mouse to just before the existing text or anywhere in between, the "A" will drop into the correct spot. But if I enter the textbox dragging the "A" to a point to the right of the text in the textbox, the textbox's caret will only go as far as just before the period at the end.  So if I drag an "A" onto the textbox to the far right, the textbox's text will become "This is a TestA." instead of "This is a test.A".

Here's the code for the DragDrop, DragEnter and DragOver events:

```
    private void txtCAR_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (btnUpdateQuestion.Text == "UPDATE!" || btnNewQuestion.Text == "Add Question")
        {
            txtCAR.Text = txtCAR.Text.Insert(txtCAR.SelectionStart, (string)e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text));
            int index = txtCAR.GetCharIndexFromPosition(txtCAR.PointToClient(Cursor.Position));
        }
    }

    private void txtCAR_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text)) e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
    }

    private void txtCAR_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {

        int index = txtCAR.GetCharIndexFromPosition(txtCAR.PointToClient(Cursor.Position));
        txtCAR.SelectionStart = index;
        txtCAR.SelectionLength = 0;
        txtCAR.Focus();
    }
```

I need the textbox's caret to go wherever I drag the mouse cursor without falling short. Why won't the textbox's caret follow the mouse cursor all the way to the end of the existing text and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: GetCharIndexFromPosition() is the problem, it can only give you the index of the last character.  You need 1 more.  A hokey workaround is to add a space to the Text and remove it again.  Less hokey but more troublesome is to use GetPositionFromCharIndex() to see how far the cursor is beyond the start of the last character.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, Hans. What should I put in the parentheses after GetPositionFromCharIndex?